# Resonance in a non-planar molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, aromaticity

I am well aware that the following compound is non-planar and hence, will not be anti-aromatic but non-aromatic.
But I wonder whether resonance will occur to some extent i.e. whether any three consecutive parallel p orbitals will lie in the same plane or not?
[image]

Comment: This can't show aromaticity as it doesn't obey huckel's rule you can think of non planarity as a measure so as to prevent anti aromaticity then why would it even planarize

Comment: Will it show resonance? Even to some extent?

Comment: Aree why would it if resonance would destabilize it

Comment: With this logic, there should exist no anti-aromatic compound.

Comment: If molecule is planar resonance will happen aromatic or anti-arometic , it doesn't matter. If non-planar than no

Comment: The p orbitals _can_ overlap to some extent, if that's what you're asking. But it won't be termed as resonance